# Typescript Generics with json dynamic keys in runtime

Tags: typescript, generics

I have this code

```
const inner = async <U, T extends { [key: string]: U[] }>(): Promise<T> => {
  // do some async staff that will produce T
  return {} as T;
}

const recursive = async <U, T extends { [key: string]: U[] }>() => {
  let count = 10;
  const arr: U[] = [];
  while (count > 0) {
    const result = await inner<U, T>();
    count--;
    arr.push(...result.key);
  }
  return arr;
}
```

Potential call methods

```
interface Inventory {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

const isInventory = (inventory: Inventory | User): inventory is Inventory => {
  return 'id' in inventory && 'name' in inventory && typeof inventory.id === 'number' && typeof inventory.name === 'string';
}

interface User {
  id: string;
  age: string;
}

const isUser = (inventory: Inventory | User): inventory is User => {
  return 'id' in inventory && 'age' in inventory && typeof inventory.id === 'string' && typeof inventory.age === 'string';
}

recursive<Inventory, { inventory: Inventory[] }>();
recursive<User, { users: User[] }>();
```

This won't work since in line `arr.push(...result.key);` key is not dynamic. Is there a way to make it dynamic? Also the fact that I need to put `Inventory` or `User` twice in when I call seems subpar, I should be able to call like `recursive<{ inventory: Inventory[] }>();`

Comment: How is your inner function supposed to know what to produce at runtime?

Comment: Typescript doesn't provide RunTime Type Information if that's what you're looking for

Comment: Maybe you're looking for something like [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WPJjqN)? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: yes @jcalz that was what I was looking for. I solve it with a similar way, I didn't put the guards though

Comment: If you don't put in the guards then you are just assuming it works at runtime?  That's not safe; it isn't clear what you want to do, but given that you wrote the guards I assumed you wanted to use them.  Shall I write up my answer?

Comment: yes please, go ahead

Answer (score 0):

The only way this could work and be possibly type safe is if your `recursive()` function actually takes parameters, so that at runtime the function knows which key to use, and how to determine if the mystery thing that comes back from `inner()` is actually assignable to an array of the type you're expecting.  You've already got some [type guard functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) around (although you're assuming you know you've got a `User | Inventory` whereas you should probably just assume `unknown` or `any` to start with).  So the calls would look like this:

```
recursive("inventory", isInventory);
recursive("users", isUser);
```

Note that if you don't pass `isInventory` or `isUser` into `recursive()` you'll just have to hope that you know for sure what key goes with what value type, and you'll end up doing the equivalent of [asserting](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to the compiler that you are right, because it won't know that.

Anyway, given *that* sort of call, you can write `recursive()` like this:

```
const recursive = async <K extends PropertyKey, T>(
  key: K,
  guard: (x: any) => x is T
) => {
  let count = 10;
  const arr: T[] = [];
  while (count > 0) {
    const result = await inner();
    if (
      (!result) ||
      (typeof result !== "object") ||
      (key in result)
    ) throw new Error("nooo");
    const v: unknown = result[key];
    if (
      !Array.isArray(v) ||
      v.every(guard)
    ) throw new Error("oh noooooez");
    count--;
    arr.push(...v);
  }
  return arr;
}
```

(Note that this function isn't recursive at all, so I'm not sure why it has such a name.)  Mostly all we've added here is: the use of `key` so we can inspect `result[key]` instead of `result.key`; and runtime type guarding to make sure that the thing `inner()` returns is actually an object with an array at the expected key, and that every element of that array is of the expected type.  If that runtime type guarding fails you get a runtime error (and presumably you'll have something more domain-specific to say than just `"oh noooo"`).

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.3.3#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-AQNhQZywwH0AEkwHpqiTkYshHAknixLRQagTmAsLQkBRoCgEDEI1GVvsICm01AMwYiAhmxmKE3bC3VTAnjAAKqMFDkFGd-sMGA99P9orSaLBiRSADkOdXKInvdbADJdzBVyWy5uENu58j97rcF8Lh2d6rxXYMIDD2B84WUJur58kN9z32YrHvogKYKulbVqutb8AIMaoPGibDqOi7NDmFZQFWYA1tEWAxOWMAQVh0EqLSuQjqgbb3he3apg+yKDuRY4UFRgG5EhFELlmwiiCuh4bluLF7geq64Ugp5SIJ-Y-jef53rRF5Pi+YGETE34Hr+-6SWKolKYeKlQYoUYaFouhIEQQJaUCvgMLOgEkE0xkoNoejmZ6qAQFZZGjvZAhAA)